# how to go multithreaded for puppeteer using worker-threads for web-automation purpose

Tags: node.js, multithreading, puppeteer, webautomation, node-worker-threads

hello so am doing some web automation and I want to open run puppeteer multithreaded what I mean like open the same page 10s of times and what I understood of what I read the worker thread is the best solution I guess?  but I didn't get how to use it properly  and I will put a sample code of what I did

```
 const { Worker, isMainThread } = require('worker_threads');
    
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer') ; 
        let scrapt = async()=>{
        
           
               
                        /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
                        /*                             Launching puppeteer                            */
                        /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
            try{                        
              const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true }) ; 
        
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.setUserAgent(
              `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36`
            );
            let Browser_b = new Date()
              await page.goto('https://www.supremenewyork.com/')
            let browser_e = new Date()
            console.log(browser_e - Browser_b)
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
let ex = [1,2,3,4]
if (isMainThread) {
    // This re-loads the current file inside a Worker instance.asdasd
    new Worker(__filename);
  } else {
    for(let val of ex) {
      scrapt();

    }
  }
```

this script opens 4 browsers but if I open more the pc lag  **ALOT** since I think it's only using one thread not using them all?
Thank u in advance and sorry for my stupidity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ever tried using Cluster? it's a good way for multi_processing and easier to use than worker_threads in my opinion here is an example from [HERE](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case it is an HTTP server
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);

  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The popular npm package "puppeteer-cluster" can handle this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-cluster

As Taha Daboussi suggest - a cluster is better than a regular worker, as the cluster worker will stay online, and there is less resources and time needed in starting / stopping puppeteer.

You stay within the "page" object and do your operations there, the stuff outside is already managed.